# AD User and Groups

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, active-directory

Is there a way to organize users in Active Directory in regards to the group they belong to using CMD? What I currently have is shown below. I would like to know if there any other alternatives.

```
NET GROUP "GROUP NAME" /domain >> C:\IT\file.txt
```

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more details to what you really want. What if I am part of 50 AD groups? How would that be represented? You want DOS or CMD (you mean using cmd shell) but you would have more flexibility if you use PowerShell, and ActiveDirectory Module with it. Get-ADGroup, Get-ADUser -prop memberof, etc. will give you more ammunition to shape the outcome.

Comment: the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet returns a `.MemberOf` list when you ask for that extended property. the property contains a list of the groups the user account is a direct member of. **_that seems to mean it won't include derived/secondary groups, but i have not tested that._**

Comment: Depends on what you mean by order them by group?  I have used Net Group to get a good list of group memberships and assign drive mappings, but it requires you build your logic on the group memerbership order that matters yourself.  You can also use DS Query and DSGet to get a lot more info on the users if you are running this on a server or system wirh the Dmin pack installed.

Comment: I would like to get a list of all users within a specific active directory OU, and get a list of all the groups that users belong to using powershell.